# Application installation failed. Could not inspect application package

Tags: ios

Details from Xcode
The title explains everything after I build I get the message, "Application installation failed" in the details, it shows the reason "Could not inspect the application package." I don't know what this means. I am new to Xcode.

> Details
>
> Unable to install "BBPlayer" Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit Code:
>   -402653103
>   -- App installation failed Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit Code: -402653103 Failure Reason: Could not inspect the application package. User Info: {
>       DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
>       "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a2c16e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109  1   DTDeviceKitBase
>   0x000000011a2c1de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792   2   DTDeviceKitBase
>   0x000000011a30156a **90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 164     3   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001020ad156 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73    4   DTDeviceKitBase
>
>   0x000000011a301301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] +
>   1589  5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011a189a25
>   __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352
>   + 4523    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001021de3ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7     7   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001021dfa92 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809    8
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f96c583
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f96d50e _dispatch_client_callout + 8     10  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff6f972ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597  11 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f973452
>   _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f97ca9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598   13 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fbc671b
>
> ### _pthread_wqthread + 290   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fbc657b start_wqthread + 15 ); }

Answer (score 4):

Please try to find a detailed error description in the device Console.

Xcode->Window->Device and Simulators->`select your device`->Open Console

You can filter or search `installd` process messages.

Comment: i check then found this error ***Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.yf2SOJ/extracted/Link.app/Frameworks/CLTokenInputView.framework; Extra info about "/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.yf2SOJ/extracted/Link.app/Frameworks/CLTokenInputView.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.yf2SOJ/extracted/Link.app/Frameworks/CLTokenInputView.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory*** can u help?

Comment: Check if removing Delivered Data helps. If not, please do not Embeded the framework into the app, as most probably this is a static framework that is already included in the binary.